# How to cross signing using Microsoft signtool

Tags: code-signing

I would appreciate if someone could teach how to sign a file using Microsoft signtool as below,

To have one certificate signed by the first authority; and one certificate signed by the second authority - both are having the same public key / fingerprint and subject line, then to sign a file to have one signature with these 2 certificates,

Your prompt reply is appreciated,

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: _"both are having the same public key / fingerprint and subject line,"_ - if two different certificates have the exact same public key then something is seriously wrong...

Comment: To cross-sign, use the `/ac <crossCertificateFileName>` [command-line option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/signtool#sign-operation-options).